# Insert breakpoint at all the lines where the method is called in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Consider case where

### File1.c

```
MethodA
{
     MethodB(); //------> Line 2
     ..
     ..
     MethodB(); //------> Line 5
}
```

### File2.c

```
MethodC
{
     MethodB();//------> Line 3
     ..
     ..
     MethodB();//------> Line 6
}
```

In above case MethodB() is called by MethodA (at line 2 and 5) and MethodC (at line 3 and 6) which exists in File1.c and File2.c respectively

In gdb, how to put breakpoint at all instances where MethodB is called. i.e., I need breakpoint to be inserted at Line 2 and 5 in File1.c, Line 3 and 5 in File2.c

In my usecase there are large number of files which is calling is MethodB, I need breakpoint in all lines.

Comment: Put the breakpoint at the start of `methodB`

Comment: Agreed with @EdHeal. Why put the breakpoint in multiple places, when you can do it in one place and have the same end result.

Comment: C has *functions* not methods.